# changing the value of attributes using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I have an element 'input[name=startdate]' with an attribute 'value="2018-06-20"'
instead of using puppeteer to interact with the calendar that is used to change the date, is there anyway I can use puppeteer to set the value instead?

something like...

let newDate = '2018-01-01'

value.innerHTML = newDate

Comment: you should just be able to `await page.$('yourinputselector').type(20180101)` - have you tried that?

Comment: when i run your code it gives me an error saying   "TypeError: page.$(...).type is not a function"

Comment: my mistake - i got the syntax messed up.  try `await page.type('yourinputselector', 20180101)`

Answer (score 12):

I was able to figure it out and I'm posting it here in case anyone else has the same problem.

```
await page.$eval('input[name=startdate]', e => e.setAttribute("value", "2018-01-01"))
```

If you want to set the date  as a variable...

```
const randomDate = '2018-01-01'
await page.$eval('input[name=startdate]', (e, randomDate) => { 
    e.setAttribute("value", randomDate),
    randomDate
    )}
```

Comment: Can someone point out how to set multiple attributes using the above?

Comment: @Swaggerboy you just change the arrow function so that it contains a block of code.

```e => {  e.setAttribute("attribute1", "2018-01-01")); e.setAttribute("attribute2", "2018-01-01")); ... }
```